# use openflow to reject (and not! just drop) packets

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

is it possible to have packages rejected instead of just dropped?
E.g. this

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow ovs_eth0 "table=0, priority=10000, ip, nw_proto=17, tp_dst=$port, actions=drop"
```

just drops it. But I would like to have it sent an explicit reject back.

Comment: What do you mean by rejected? An explicit TCP RST? A HTTP error code? What about UDP?

Comment: Sorry not beeing exact. My idea was to have something like --reject-with tcp-reset in iptables. So TCP RST would be nice.